# Access instance variable through coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I'm trying to access some ruby instance variables through a coffeescript file.  At what point do instance variables become defined?  For example, when I try the following:

```
$(window).load () ->    
 $('#s3-uploader').S3Uploader
    additional_data: {project_id: <%= @project.id %>, step_id: <%= @step.id %>, user_id: <%= current_user.id %>}
```

I get the error

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
  (in /images.js.coffee.erb)
```

I know that @project should be defined, though, since I use it on the page when it's loaded.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CoffeeScript and your page are most likely in different views. Thus, having `@project` available when rendering your page says nothing about its availability when you're rendering your JavaScript. The easiest way to transfer this is to define a JavaScript variable inside your page view. For instance, if you're using Haml or Slim:

```
coffeescript:
  window.MyModule.project_id = #{ @project.id }
```

and then change your code to

```
additional_data: { project_id: window.MyModule.project_id, ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  If my page is loaded via a partial, how would I define the project_id variable?  Would it be something like <script>window.MyModule.project_id = <%=@project.id%></script> ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's partial or not, but what engine you're using. If you're using ERb (as it seems), then yes. Given that you're writing in regular JavaScript and not CoffeeScript, a semicolon would be advisable (even though unnecessary) as good JS style.